# Writing to a .csv file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to write data, which comes in as a QR Code and I want to scan the data to a .csv. The user has to define the file name before hand, so they can open up files they scanned to before, or make a new one. The data comes in formatted as "name,phone#,email" which would look something like this:

```
joe,1234567890,joe@joe.com
```

The main thing to see from that is the data comes in as a string with commas so writing to csv is easy.
I have seen many questions answered about writing to csv in java, and my main problem is not that, but how to use the android file system to open existing or make new files.

If you need to see something else from the app, I can attach what you need.

Thank you for your help!!

Edit 1: Got rid of extraneous code

Edit 2: Clarified question

Comment: Way too much code. Show minimum to demonstrate you issue.

Comment: Writing CSV data from Java has been covered many many times already. How has your Question not been addressed by the existing Questions and Answers?

Comment: it was more about the android studio file system than the writing to csv. Probably should have clarified that

Comment: You still can still edit your Question for clarity and brevity. If QR codes and Google Sheets are not part of your technical issue, omit them. If there is something about writing a CSV file to the Android file system that has not yet been covered in existing Questions (after you searched thoroughly through those existing Questions and Answers), then explain your concern. If  you do that, the Question can be reopened. Closing a Question does not have to be permanent.

Comment: I edited it to clarify that I am looking for more of the android file system help, is this good now?

Comment: Hello, did you figure it out by any chance?